# AutoCAD 2016/SQL Server 2014 - Error 91 Object Variable or With Block variable not set

Tags: autocad

I'm having trouble setting a record in SQL using VBA. See the images of what I have setup so far. The question is, where am I missing a switch to get this record creation to work? I know the code works fine on SQL Server 2008. But I'm setting this up on a new install of SQL Server 2014 that has nothing to do with the successful configuration using SQL Server 2008. I have more images, but this site will only let me post 2 for now. If more info is needed just let me know what you seek.

[Code Causing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aob9C.png)

[SQL Server Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0iLt.png)

Comment: Since posting this...I removed the table USERS and trying to connect with the user set in Security.... which is GS7/Chris....and it still won't work. Do you have to issue an OPEN command? Because that wasn't required on SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Made further progress. I'm connected now....but the tables in SQL seem to be my problem with this issue.